# Circular reference when calling PHP script from C++ program

Tags: php, c++

When I called a PHP script from a C++ program that was called from a different PHP script, my server crashed. I'm assuming a circular reference occurred.

I'm using a GoDaddy dedicated server with CentOS 6.9.

Here is the first PHP script (named script1.php):

```
<?php
    passthru('test_cpp');
?>
```

Here is the C++ program (named test_cpp)

```
#include "iostream"
#include "cstdlib"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::system("/usr/bin/php script2.php") <<std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the second PHP script (named script2.php):

```
<?php
    #!/usr/bin/php
    echo "Hello";
?>
```

I would expect the first PHP script to display the output of the second script. Instead, the browser displayed an hourglass for a minute, and two minutes later the MySQL database stopped working so I had to restart the server.

Comment: I don't see why you would get a circular reference from that. What does your log files say?

Comment: Which particular log file would have info about this issue, after I restarted my server?

Comment: Something like /var/log/httpd/error_log (different distros have them in different places, but your webserver's log is what we're looking for)